# Populate a column in a dataframe based on if statement for column in another dataframe - Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Lets say dataframe 1, df1 looks like the following

```
    A B C
    1 2 a
    3 4 c
    3 4 e
```

And I want to create a column D, only if column C values matches the column B in dataframe 2, where df2 looks like the following:

```
    A B    C    D E
    1 2   a,d   4 5
    2 3   d,c   3 6
    3 4   f,e,j 7 2
```

If df1['C'] == df2['C'], return the corresponding value in df2['D']
So the result I would want in df1 new column D is

```
    A B C D
    1 2 a 4
    3 4 c 3
    3 4 e 7
```

As you can see, in df2['C'] it has multiple values in the column as long as df1['C'] matches one of them, then condition is fulfilled and new column 'D' should be populated

I have tried df1['D'] = np.where(df1['C']==df2['C'], df2['D']), it did not work.

Your assistance is much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Hi Raymond. Welcome to stack overflow. Please edit your question to include relevant dfs right in the question as copyable text, not as images. Make sure code is formatted as code using backticks or Ctrl+K or the code formatting button

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split and column and merge with another column while concatenating in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65711410/split-and-column-and-merge-with-another-column-while-concatenating-in-pandas)

Comment: Hello, the suggested post provides some clarification with the .map method but I don't need to map my column "C" (the one with the multiple values separated by a comma) into my df1

Essentially, I just need a method to check that the values in df1 column "C" matches 1 of the multiple values in df2 column "C" and then return the corresponding value from df2 column "D"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `df2.C.str.split(',')` to create a python list from your column `C` and then use `zip` to create a tuple for every row on each dataframe. The list comprehension will use `s1 in s2` to generate a list with `True` or `False` values that can be used over the `df2.D` to populate the new `D` column in `df1`.

```
contain = [s1 in s2 for s1, s2 in zip(df1.C, df2.C.str.split(','))]
df1['D'] = df2.D[contain]
```

Comment: Thank you, I will give that method a try.  I actually ended re-structuring my dataset to side step that problem, but I will definitely try your suggested solution for learning purposes.