# Split and column and merge with another column while concatenating in pandas

Tags: pandas, concatenation

Create a concatenation of values in pandas based on values of another column

I have 2 dataframes

df1

```
NAME    CODE
andy    a,d
roger   b
danny   d
cole
```

df2

```
CODE    MATERIAL
a       paper
b       plastic
b       metal
d       wood
e       glass
```

I want to update df2 with the materials column and concatenate where necessary

Intended result:

```
CODE    MATERIAL    NAME
a       paper       andy
b       plastic     roger
b       metal       roger
d       wood        andy, danny
e       glass
```

how do i go about this?

Answer (score 2):

You can first create a code to name mapping based on df1, and then use the mapping to create the needed column in df2:

```
# revert NAME to CODE mapping as CODE to NAME
code_2_name = df1.assign(CODE = lambda x: x.CODE.str.split(','))
                 .explode('CODE')
                 .groupby('CODE')
                 .agg(','.join)  
code_2_name
#            NAME
#CODE            
#a           andy
#b          roger
#d     andy,danny

# create the NAME column based on the code to name mapping
df2['NAME'] = df2.CODE.map(code_2_name.NAME)
df2
#  CODE MATERIAL        NAME
#0    a    paper        andy
#1    b  plastic       roger
#2    b    metal       roger
#3    d     wood  andy,danny
#4    e    glass         NaN
```